# Trouble subscribing to channels via PFInstallation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm setting up push notifications for my first app and I'm having trouble adding more channels to my channels array in PFInstallation on Parse. So far I've added 2 channels that worked fine, then I tried adding another with the string "Rabies - 1yr". I figured it was because the "-" but Parse documentation says dashes are ok. Now my app keeps getting hung up on that and I get the following error statement anytime I try to save any other channel with normal characters:

"Error saving Installation: Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=112 "Bad channel name: Rabies 1-yr" UserInfo={code=112, temporary=0, error=Bad channel name: Rabies 1-yr, NSLocalizedDescription=Bad channel name: Rabies 1-yr})"

Here's how I've been saving:

```
let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
currentInstallation.addUniqueObject(self.vaccineDocument, forKey: "channels")
currentInstallation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (Bool, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        print("saved new installation: \(currentInstallation)")
    } else {
        print("Error saving Installation: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The worst part is that neither of my print statements show in the debug. Instead I just get the above error whether the self.vaccineDocument = "Rabies - 1yr" or not! Any ideas?

Comment: It might be whitespace in the channel name.  Can you try: "Rabies1yr" or even "Rabies-1-yr"?

Comment: Thank you @danh! It was bc of the white space. If you put this as the answer I will up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Channel names must be machine readable, and only understandable (not pretty) for humans.  A good strategy for naming them would be to exclude whitespace, since it adds only a little readability but a lot of opportunity for error.

Consider, for example, using `"Rabies1yr"` or even `"Rabies-1-yr"` instead of `"Rabies 1-yr"`.

Comment: Yes I just got rid of the space and it worked. I just did a little work-around for every time I had spaces with the simple method  stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString(" ", withString: ""). Problem solved!